# Azure iisnode angularJS 1.x app infinite loop when using $http

Tags: angularjs, azure, iisnode

I'm serving an angular 1.x app using iisnode/Azure from an index.html. The routing works fine, but whenever I load any **view** that makes an $http resource call it seems to go into an infinite loop. The **api** is hosted on a different instance. I have tested hitting the instance apiBase/ in postman and it returns the expected response. My **web.config** for iisnode is below:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
       <clear />

    <rule name="AngularJS Conditions" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(css/.*|images/.*|scripts/.*)" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
      <action type="None" />
    </rule>

    <rule name="AngularJS Wildcard" enabled="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="index.html" />
    </rule>

  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Any help is super useful. Very new to iisnode/Azure.

Answer (score 0):

Actually if you are running a pure angularJs SPA on Azure Web App, you don't have necessary to configure a `web.config` to force the iisnode to execute your application. As the angularJs application is totally pure javascript application and which is ran via the interpreter on client browsers. And the rewrite mode you configured in IIS may the criminal which may break the route event in anguarJs application.

You can try to remove the `web.config` file and restart your Azure Web Apps.

Furthermore, as I cannot reproduce your issue on my side, if it is convenient of you, please provide the problem project repo on GitHub or anywhere else for us to detect the issue.

## update

It may be a common issue if you are using `html5mode` of angularjs route provider.

Please try to modify your `web.config` with the following content:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
     <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="AngularJS Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: That is somewhat correct, but when I go to say baseUrl/routeName directly (i.e from a link or hard refresh) Azure returns - **The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.**

Comment: Do you mean the entire angularjs application responded the 404 error, or the view template you tried to invoke from angular route provider via `templateUrl` responded the 404 error? Could you directly browse the template via the template's url? And could you tell me the extension of the view template?

Comment: No, I'm fairly sure that's an azure error. I can hit the root `/` url fine and angular load as expected. I can also manoeuvre throughout the angular app as expected, but if I go directly to a route such as `/transactions` (say in a new tab or with a hard refresh then I am given that error)

Comment: As it works fine on my side including the angular route module. Could you please provide your repository?

Comment: Unsure as to how I'm going to provide you with my repository. I won't be able to share it with you as it contains sensitive info? What do you need from my repo? Folder structure or a particular file?